# Creating User For Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

When I enter `su postgres` it is asking for a password and I did not set any prior password. 
I am using a Django book and have installed PostgreSQL with `sudo apt-get install PostgreSQL PostgreSQL-contrib` I installed it within a virtual environment the instructions are vague on where to install so I just install it in there. Also installed the install the **psycopg2 PostgreSQL adapter for Python** with 
`pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.4`. I am now in the next step to create a user for the **PostgreSQL** but can't pass that step the instructions provided are to enter `su postgres` and immediately after `createuser -dp user-name` and it is asking for a password. I have entered my superuser password but showing authentication failure. 
Thanks

Comment: Whose instructions are you following?  Can you provide a link?

Comment: it's a book **Django 3 by example**

Answer (score 0):

in your linux terminal write the commands

```
sudo -s
su postgres
psql
```

then you connect to postgres

to create a user from psql you type

```
create user  username with encrypted password 'password';
```

to create a database with specific owner you type

```
create database databasename with encoding 'utf8' owner username;
```

to exit from psql you type

```
\q
```

last but not least to alter the password for user postgres with psql run the command

```
alter user postgres with encrypted password 'password';
```

then restart the postgresql server

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Comment: Hy, thanks, but after entering psql it is giving the following error `psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?` I have tried deleting everything and installing according to an answer I found with `sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*  `

Comment: to check if running  type  sudo service postgresql status

Comment: The server was not running, while searching I encountered this [this article](https://medium.com/@harshityadav95/postgresql-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-6dc751ac1ff3) maybe someone in the future here would come across the same problem. Thanks for you help